# How to implement connection-pooling efficiently?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, datasource, connection-pooling

My code to connect to database is using BasicDataSource as following, referring to [Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496391/difference-between-basicdatasource-and-poolingdatasource) I suppose my code creates a physical connection to database ONCE and then provide pool connections afterward.
My question is that, does my code provide pool connection?, if it does, should I keep the connection section of the code in the following method or in the constructor to provide efficient pooling ? and how should be the annotations for the state of the class ? @Stateful?

```
        // Connection section start
        BasicDataSource bs = new BasicDataSource();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            bs.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            bs.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDb");
            bs.setUsername("root");
            bs.setPassword("");
            con = bs.getConnection();
            System.out.println("Connecting");
        // Connection section end

            ps = con.prepareStatement("Select *"
                    + " from Client WHERE Username = ? ");
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();
            if (r.next()) {
                con.close();
                return "true";
            }
```

Comment: Use the Apache Commonds DBCP connection pool. Don't write this stuff yourself.

Comment: @EJP, which stuff? would you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BasicDataSource` implements connection pooling. However, if you create a new pool each time then it's useless. Create the data source once and reuse it everywhere.

Usually, in Java EE you *inject* the data source. That is, the container manages the data source for you. Injecting a datasource in a bean is as simple as

```
@Resource
private DataSource movieDatabase;
```

See [this example](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-datasource/README.html). Configuring the datasource depends on the container you are using, though. The same data source can be used for stateful and statless beans.